# How to iterate from a given number range?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In an ember template. Is it possible to do something similar to pseudo code:

```
 <ul>
  {{#each [1..100] as |item|}}
    <li>{{#link-to "articles.index" (query-params page=item)}}{{item}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

Which would create something similar to:

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href="localhost/articles?page=1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="localhost/articles?page=2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="localhost/articles?page=3">3</a></li>
  // so forth
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, but it's easy to implement with sub-expressions in HTMLBars. So if you create a helper like so:

```
App.RangeHelper = Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {
  var range = [];
  for(var i=params[0]; i < params[1]; ++i){
    range.push(i);
  }
  return range;
});
```

You can do:

```
{{#each (range 1 100) as |item|}}
  <li>{{#link-to "articles.index" (query-params page=item)}}{{item}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

I'm mimicking the python range function, so keep in mind it ends at 99 in my example.